# Mapping optimal sensor placement problem to Art Gallery Problem

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

I am trying to design an algorithm for `optimal sensor placements` in a given area. I researched in this domain and found `Art Gallery Problem`. However, this problem assumes that the Guards can see all the way through, till the perimeter. However, for sensors, there is a limit of visibility. So is there any way of mapping Art Gallery problem with Optimal sensor placement?

I would be grateful if someone could throw some light on this, or if they could guide me towards the right resources.

Comment: Exactly what are the limits on visibility? What forms of galleries are you interested in? What are you trying to optimize here?

Comment: @vonbrand The gallery here is a plane land. And the guards are sensors for monitoring fire. So I need to monitor the entire area, with minimum ( optimal ) number of sensors. Hope you get my problem statement now.

Comment: "The gallery here is a plane land". Do you model the land with a simple polygon? or a polygon with holes?

Comment: @Hoda the land can be a polygon with holes. Not necessarily a continuous plane like a square, etc. It can have holes in between.